# Golang | Escape regex special characters to create a valid string for regexp.MustCompile() method

Tags: regex, go

When I try to pass this regex as a string between `'` or `"` it throws errors because of invalid string.
I am pretty confused, how can I escape special characters to create a valid regex string for input of `regexp.MustCompile()` method.

here is my regex (which is not a valid string input for this method):

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("^(Yii::t\()(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\,(\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\")\)$")
```

Comment: Did you try using **raw** strings, e.g. `\`foo bar\`` instead of `"foo bar"`? (https://play.golang.org/p/HnKl1blnOMK) More here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Comment: @mkopriva I didn't know about ``. I'm pretty new to golang. thanks anyway